# Web framework visualizing decision rules (interactive graph)

Tags: java, graphs, web

I need web framework for creating visualization of decision rules. This is project for my master thesis (only 4 months remains). My vision is:

> Visitor uploads file with decision rules. Next he can explore some
>   information of uploaded decision rules. I'd like to present
>   information in: tables (sort, filter), graph (read only but
>   interactive: zoom, choose, filter objects, color them...).

I am database programmer, so I am amateur in web programming. I've tried to learn spring but it seems to be rather complicated. I would like my software to be also easy to deploy and I'm afraid it will be difficult in spring framework (despite using Spring Boot).

Operating system: I use windows, but application should be accesible on every system.

Budget: it is master thesis, so I wouldn't like to invest.

Features:

- interactive graphs,
- efficient - deal with many nodes in graph (up to 20,000),
- tables with filtering, sorting,
- able to use parser of decision rules implemented in Java (jar library).

I think it will be necessary to store data in client's cache to be efficient enough. Maybe, it would be better to create it as a software application. But:
Web application has some advantages: it can be run instantly by another scientists without downloading software and avoiding problems with configuration.
I wonder if it would be good idea to present all things on one page (one URL) to be as interactive as possible.

**What do you think about it?**
**What web framework could you advice?**